# Remembering users selection from one page to the next

Tags: php, javascript

on my website, the user has several options such as language, date and region. when the user clicks anyone of those all is fine, the website adapts to the specific choices, but when they go to another page they loose all their choices, it would be nice if i found a way to keep them for their entire visit or perhaps 24hours.

example: bob goes onto my website, under the region setting, he clicks UK and as a result the website adapts and shows him a UK flag as a result. However, he when he goes to the next page he looses the flag and his region setting and has to choose his region setting all over again.

This is what I want to fix. I will post the whole code up in case this may help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Loughborough University | Students Union</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/changesheets.js"></script>
<?php include("scripts/lang_change.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/factoid_randomise.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/greeting.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/menu_change.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/lang_select.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/geo_loc_change.php"); ?>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/grey_white.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/orange_black.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/offwhite_blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//Specify affected tags. Add or remove from list:
var tgs = new Array( 'div','td','tr','li','p');

//Specify spectrum of different font sizes:
var szs = new Array( 'xx-small','x-small','small','medium','large','x-large','xx-large' );
var startSz = 2;

function ts( trgt,inc ) {
if (!document.getElementById) return
var d = document,cEl = null,sz = startSz,i,j,cTags;

sz += inc;
if ( sz < 0 ) sz = 0;
if ( sz > 6 ) sz = 6;
startSz = sz;

if (!( cEl = d.getElementById( trgt ) ) ) cEl = d.getElementsByTagName( trgt )[ 0 ];

cEl.style.fontSize = szs[ sz ];

for ( i = 0 ; i < tgs.length ; i++ ) {
cTags = cEl.getElementsByTagName( tgs[ i ] );
for ( j = 0 ; j < cTags.length ; j++ ) cTags[ j ].style.fontSize = szs[ sz ];
}
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">


<div id="header">



<?php 


if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'Japanese' :
echo "<div id='logo_japanese'></div>";
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo "<div id='logo_chinese'></div>";
break;
default:
echo "<div id='logo'></div>";
break;
}
}
?>

<ruby style='float:right;  margin-top:-80px;'>
<rb><a href="javascript:ts('body',2)"><button style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/textchange.png); width:31px; height:29px; border:none; '></button></a> </rb>

<rb><a href="javascript:ts('body',-1)" ><button style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/textchangeb.png); width:23px; height:29px; border:none;'></button></a></rb>
<rb><button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(1)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/theme1.png); width:29px; height:29px; border:none; '></button></rb>
<rb><button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(2)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/theme2.png);width:29px; height:29px;border:none;' ></button></rb>
<rb><button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(3)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/theme3.png);width:29px; height:29px;border:none;' ></button></rb>
<rb><button style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/Britishflag.png);width:48px; height:20px;border:none;' ></button></rb>
</ruby>

<div class='greeting'>
<?php 


if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo welcome($tz_ger,$greetings_ger);
break;case 'Korean' :
echo welcome($tz_kor,$greetings_kor);
break;case 'Russian' :
echo welcome($tz_rus,$greetings_rus);
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo welcome($tz_jap,$greetings_jap);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo welcome($tz_chi,$greetings_chi);
break;
default:
echo welcome($tz_eng,$greetings_eng);
break;
}
}
?></div>
</div>


<div id="line"></div>

<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {  
case 'German' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_ger,$title);
break;
case 'Korean' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_kor,$title);
break;
case 'Russian' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_rus,$title);
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_jap,$title);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_chi,$title);
break;
default:
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_eng,$title);
break;
}
}

?>


<div id="line"></div>
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_ger,$geoplugin);

break;case 'Korean' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_kor,$geoplugin);

break;case 'Russian' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_rus,$geoplugin);

break;case 'Japanese' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_jap,$geoplugin);

break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_chi,$geoplugin);

break;
default:
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_eng,$geoplugin);
break;
}
}

?>
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'Russian' :
echo "<div id='welcome_pic_russian'>";
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo "<div id='welcome_pic_japanese'>";
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo "<div id='welcome_pic_chinese'>";
break;
default:
echo "<div id='welcome_pic'>
";
break;
}
}

?>





<div id="play_feature">
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo selectLang($h_ger,$lang_ger,$values,$h2_ger,$lang_ger2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;case 'Korean' :
echo selectLang($h_kor,$lang_kor,$values,$h2_kor,$lang_kor2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
case 'Russian' :
echo selectLang($h_rus,$lang_rus,$values,$h2_rus,$lang_rus2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo selectLang($h_jap,$lang_jap,$values,$h2_jap,$lang_jap2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo selectLang($h_chi,$lang_chi,$values,$h2_chi,$lang_chi2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
default:
echo selectLang($h_eng,$lang_eng1,$values,$h2_eng,$lang_eng2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
}
}

?>




<?php
/*
@author geoPlugin (gp_support@geoplugin.com)
@copyright Copyright geoPlugin (gp_support@geoplugin.com)
*/

require_once('scripts/geoplugin.class.php');

$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();

$geoplugin->locate();

?>

<div id='menu2' style='width:250px; margin-left:-40px;'> 
</div>
<div style="color:#616161; margin-left:-20px;">
<blockquote>&#8216<?php 


if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsg);
break;case 'Korean' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsk);
break;case 'Russian' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsr);
break;case 'Japanese' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsj);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsc);
break;
default:
echo randomFactoid($factoids);
break;
}
}


?>&#8217</blockquote>
</div>

</font>
</div></div>

<div id="homepage_text">
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo "<p>text</p>";
break;
case 'Korean' :
echo "<p>text.</p> ";
break;
case 'Russian' :
echo "<p>text </p>";
break;

case 'Japanese' :
echo "<p>text</p>";
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo "<p>text</p>";
break;
default:
echo "<p>text</p>";
break;
}
}

?>



</div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This may be doable in cookies/sessions or something similar but i dnt know how i could incorporate cookies/session into this with the way i have coded it.

Any other suggestions other than cookies or sessions are welcome.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**VERY IMPORTANT UPDATE**
**After the suggestions below i tried this code:**

```
<?php
session_start(); //put this at the top of your script on all pages that need to remember
if(isset($_POST['languages']))
{
    $_SESSION['languages'] = $_POST['languages'];
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Loughborough University | Students Union</title>



<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/changesheets.js"></script>
<?php include("scripts/lang_change.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/factoid_randomise.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/greeting.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/menu_change.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/lang_select.php"); ?>
<?php include("scripts/geo_loc_change.php"); ?>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/grey_white.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/orange_black.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/offwhite_blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//Specify affected tags. Add or remove from list:
var tgs = new Array( 'div','td','tr','li','p');

//Specify spectrum of different font sizes:
var szs = new Array( 'xx-small','x-small','small','medium','large','x-large','xx-large' );
var startSz = 2;

function ts( trgt,inc ) {
if (!document.getElementById) return
var d = document,cEl = null,sz = startSz,i,j,cTags;

sz += inc;
if ( sz < 0 ) sz = 0;
if ( sz > 6 ) sz = 6;
startSz = sz;

if (!( cEl = d.getElementById( trgt ) ) ) cEl = d.getElementsByTagName( trgt )[ 0 ];

cEl.style.fontSize = szs[ sz ];

for ( i = 0 ; i < tgs.length ; i++ ) {
cTags = cEl.getElementsByTagName( tgs[ i ] );
for ( j = 0 ; j < cTags.length ; j++ ) cTags[ j ].style.fontSize = szs[ sz ];
}
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">


<div id="header">



<?php 

if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'Japanese' :
echo "<div id='logo_japanese'></div>";
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo "<div id='logo_chinese'></div>";
break;
default:
echo "<div id='logo'></div>";
break;
}
}
?>

<ruby style='float:right;  margin-top:-80px;'>
<rb><a href="javascript:ts('body',2)"><button style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/textchange.png); width:31px; height:29px; border:none; '></button></a> </rb>

<rb><a href="javascript:ts('body',-1)" ><button style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/textchangeb.png); width:23px; height:29px; border:none;'></button></a></rb>
<rb><button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(1)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/theme1.png); width:29px; height:29px; border:none; '></button></rb>
<rb><button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(2)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/theme2.png);width:29px; height:29px;border:none;' ></button></rb>
<rb><button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(3)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/theme3.png);width:29px; height:29px;border:none;' ></button></rb>
<rb><button style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/Britishflag.png);width:48px; height:20px;border:none;' ></button></rb>
</ruby>

<div class='greeting'>
<?php 


if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo welcome($tz_ger,$greetings_ger);
break;case 'Korean' :
echo welcome($tz_kor,$greetings_kor);
break;case 'Russian' :
echo welcome($tz_rus,$greetings_rus);
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo welcome($tz_jap,$greetings_jap);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo welcome($tz_chi,$greetings_chi);
break;
default:
echo welcome($tz_eng,$greetings_eng);
break;
}
}
?></div>
</div>


<div id="line"></div>

<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {  
case 'German' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_ger,$title);
break;
case 'Korean' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_kor,$title);
break;
case 'Russian' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_rus,$title);
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_jap,$title);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_chi,$title);
break;
default:
echo makeMenu($links,$tabs_eng,$title);
break;
}
}

?>


<div id="line"></div>
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_ger,$geoplugin);

break;case 'Korean' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_kor,$geoplugin);

break;case 'Russian' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_rus,$geoplugin);

break;case 'Japanese' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_jap,$geoplugin);

break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_chi,$geoplugin);

break;
default:
echo changeGeoLoc($GeoLoc,$details_eng,$geoplugin);
break;
}
}

?>
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'Russian' :
echo "<div id='welcome_pic_russian'>";
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo "<div id='welcome_pic_japanese'>";
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo "<div id='welcome_pic_chinese'>";
break;
default:
echo "<div id='welcome_pic'>
";
break;
}
}

?>





<div id="play_feature">
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo selectLang($h_ger,$lang_ger,$values,$h2_ger,$lang_ger2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;case 'Korean' :
echo selectLang($h_kor,$lang_kor,$values,$h2_kor,$lang_kor2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
case 'Russian' :
echo selectLang($h_rus,$lang_rus,$values,$h2_rus,$lang_rus2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
case 'Japanese' :
echo selectLang($h_jap,$lang_jap,$values,$h2_jap,$lang_jap2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo selectLang($h_chi,$lang_chi,$values,$h2_chi,$lang_chi2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
default:
echo selectLang($h_eng,$lang_eng1,$values,$h2_eng,$lang_eng2,$countries,$day,$month,$year);
break;
}
}

?>




<?php
/*
@author geoPlugin (gp_support@geoplugin.com)
@copyright Copyright geoPlugin (gp_support@geoplugin.com)
*/

require_once('scripts/geoplugin.class.php');

$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();

$geoplugin->locate();

?>

<div id='menu2' style='width:250px; margin-left:-40px;'> 
</div>
<div style="color:#616161; margin-left:-20px;">
<blockquote>&#8216<?php 


if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsg);
break;case 'Korean' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsk);
break;case 'Russian' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsr);
break;case 'Japanese' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsj);
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo randomFactoid($factoidsc);
break;
default:
echo randomFactoid($factoids);
break;
}
}


?>&#8217</blockquote>
</div>

</font>
<a href="http://s06.flagcounter.com/more/7ydE" ><img src="http://s06.flagcounter.com/count/7ydE/bg=FFFFFF/txt=000000/border=CCCCCC/columns=3/maxflags=25/viewers=Visitors/labels=0/pageviews=1/" alt="free counters" style="border:none; margin-left:15px;"/></a></div></div>

<div id="homepage_text">
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['languages']))
{
        $_POST['languages'] = array('English');
}

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {
switch ($language) {
case 'German' :
echo "<p> </p>";
break;
case 'Korean' :
echo "<p></p> ";
break;
case 'Russian' :
echo "<p> </p>";
break;

case 'Japanese' :
echo "<p>。</p>";
break;
case 'Chinese' :
echo "<p></p>";
break;
default:
echo "<p></p>";
break;
}
}

?>



</div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**WHICH DIDNT WORK. ANY reasons why, seem to have done everything people have told me?****

Comment: if you vote this down explain why.

Comment: @Ryan --- why did you include ruby-on-rails on this question? (I did not downvote, but before I edit I wanted to ask)

Comment: @Jesse Only included it because there may be a ruby on rails solution.

Comment: @Ryan: there is (session variables), but your code is php. I recommend you remove rails, html, and cookies

Comment: Does the user have the ability to select more than one language at a time, as your code suggests, or are they limited to one language?

Comment: Just a tip to make it easier for people to understand your question in the future: You don't need to post your whole code. You can cut out stuff, like the javascript, which is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: An advice for the future: You should think about seperating your bits of code better. You could put all PHP logic to the beginning of the file and the HTML code at the bottom, which would make the whole code better readable and potentially less error-prone. Also you have some copy & paste parts which you should redesign to have less code repetition.

Comment: Refering to your question: What exactly does not work right now? Try a "vardump($_SESSION);" after the session_start() expression to see if there is anything stored in the session.

Comment: Sessions are the right way to do this. Now, you could try to light a fire using two branches and your hands, but it's much easier with matchsticks.

Comment: The only problem with the session variable is that the user can't change his setting anymore, if that is what you want! But it should ne possible using hidden input variable, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sessions or Cookies are definitely the best way to do it:
The thing is that you have to have a way to connect it with the user.
Technically you could store it in a database and either store a cookie on the user's computer that says which database entry to read or even store the user's ip and relate it to the user that way (although that's a pretty unreliable method). But that's all probably an overkill for what you want to do.*

## **Here is how to incorporate sessions into your code:**

### Posting only one language

For a start lets reformat what you already have.
You have `$_POST['languages']` which is actually an array that contains one result.
In that case you may as well make it a string and call it `$_POST['language']`

You also must remember to post it correctly (in the singular) when the user originally chooses his language.

### First off you have to start the session at the top of the page:

```
session_start();
```

### Next you have to save the user's selection to a session variable.

We are going to check if the user has selected a language (from the `$_POST` variable) and, if yes, assign it to a `$_SESSION` variable.

```
if ($_POST['language']) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
}
```

The session variable functions identical to any other variable, but it will carry on from page to page until the session ends.

### Now we are going to check what the language is

This is pretty simple. In your example you checked what the language was by finding what the user had 'posted':

```
isset($_POST['languages'])
```

In our new code, we are going to check the session variable, which we have just saved:

```
$_SESSION['language']
```

### Choosing the right language

No need to make `$_POST['languages']` an array and then use a `foreach` to loop through it.

A simpler way of doing it would be like this:

```
switch($_SESSION['language']) {
    case "german": //do german suff
    case "english": //do english suff
    etc...
}
```

Additionally, you first checked if the session tag was empty and then put a value if it wasn't.
You can skip that step and instead put inside the `switch() { }` at the end, after all the cases:

```
default: //do default language stuff
```

Answer (score 11):

The session can be used at this situation. You can assign these values in the session variable and can access on all the pages of application.

```
$_SESSION['somevar']='someval';
```

Comment: could you possibly try to make it any more specific to one of my variables? would be a great help.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a serious look at using **gettext** for manageable localization support. Instead of doing conditionals for every piece of your page, you'll simply call a function like `<?php _('Welcome!') ?>` and it will be automatically translated according to your language setting.

1. Download the [library](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/)
2. Follow these [instructions](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/)

Answer (score 4):

**As a session:**

```
session_start(); //put this at the top of your script on all pages that need to remember
if(isset($_POST['languages']))
{
    $_SESSION['languages'] = $_POST['languages'];
}
```

Then change:

```
foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
```

to

foreach ($_SESSION['languages'] as $language) {

**As a cookie:**

```
    if(isset($_POST['languages']))
{
    setcookie('language', $_POST['languages'], 7776000) //sets cookie for 90 days, or 7776000 seconds
}
```

and change
     foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {

to

```
   foreach ($_COOKIE['languages'] as $language) {
```

I believe this answer is complete... do you intend to support multiple languages?

Comment: Wow, what a fantastic answer thankyou. Yes I do intend to support several languages

Comment: i'll look in to it when i get home, at work now so i could only throw together the basic concept for you.

Comment: The update isn't working because you're checking and assigning languages to `$_POST` instead of `$_SESSION`. Check your if statements and see if they match up with the examples Chris gave you.

Comment: Also you're trying to use a foreach loop on the session which isn't an array.

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO + SOURCE:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/remembering-users-selection-from-one-page-to-the-next/

```
<?php
 session_start();
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
  define(LANGUAGE, $_SESSION['lang']);
}
else {
  define(LANGUAGE, 'en_GB');
}
include 'languages/'.LANGUAGE.'.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the top of the code, write "session_start();"
After that, whenever an update is submitted, update the matching $_SESSION array's index (you may choose names such as "region", "language", "lng" - the choice is up to you as long as you are consistent). Then, whenever you are loading a page, load it depending on the value in the $_SESSION array. 
See also: http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

After all related session updates - one main thing is that how you set your `$_SESSION` variables. It shows that you get it from `$_POST`, but there is no place in code that actually posts the value. You mention that someone clicks to change the language - is it done via the form submit, or via a URL?

Add a dump of `$_SESSION` variable right after you set the language value, and see if it actually gets set... I have a feeling that you never reach that line of code as you don't have a `$_POST` variable defined anywhere...

Comment: after dumping it and selecting chinese it sed Array ( [languages] => Array ( [0] => Chinese ) )

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the session variable is that the user can't change his setting anymore, if that is what you want! But it should be possible using hidden input variable on each page, too. In fact I'm using hidden input variable all the time and also I compress this variable so it is quite fast and secure and also I'm using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to read the lengthy example code. Please reduce the size of a non working example.

The PHP session code relies on a SESSION ID. There are **two ways to transport** these ID from web page to web page: POST and GET. But what I can see is, that **you support only one**, the POST method. In case of GET you must add the SESSION ID variable SID to the URL used for navigation.

The details of SESSION ID handling are described in the PHP documentation:

[Passing the Session ID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)